# Can I group by a variable and apply a transform?

Tags: pandas

Here is some sample data I am working with

```
Group   Measure
B   10.59
C   7.94
B   8.67
C   10.4
B   10.1
C   10.11
A   9.08
B   10.24
C   9.67
B   10.49
```

I'd like to find the Z score of Measure according to the entries of Group. This amounts to grouping by each entry in Group and taking the z score of the  data.

Naive attempts like

`df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: zscore(x.Measure))` result in an array in each data frame cell.

Is there anyway I can apply a transform to a column according to a grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd 
df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: stats.zscore(x))

    Measure
0  0.821669
1 -1.666544
2 -1.936382
3  0.911883
4  0.117792
5  0.607922
6       NaN # single value do not have std so the result will be NaN
7  0.318900
8  0.146740
9  0.678021
```

Comment: Oh great, I didn't know about transform.  Thanks!

Comment: @DemetriP Good night !  ( - _ - ) ZzzzZ